# echo/print issue in php while loop

Tags: php, ajax, loops, echo, while-loop

I need a fix for this.
here is just part of my code

```
<?php
$number = 30;
while($number > 0) {
 $number--;
 sleep(30);
 print "$number . Posted<br>";

}
?>
```

The loop process in  the loop is actually much bigger, i just put the important stuff.

Anyways as you can see it should print 
30 posted
(wait 30 seconds)
29 Posted
(wait 30 seconds)
28 Posted
(wait 30 seconds)

But instead it waits till the loop is over, then just prints it all at once. Is there a fix for this? I was thinking an ajax method, but I dont know of any.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nice that everyone explained why.

This is because by default PHP will process everything before it 'flushed' anything out to the browser. By just printing each line, it's storing that information in the buffer which will all be printed simultaneously once PHP is finished executing.

If you want PHP to flush that content to the browser immediately after the line, you need to call `flush()` after each one, then it will output the text one line at a time after each one is called.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after printing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [flush](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)()

Answer (score 1):

An example of a loop with flush() is

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
 {
   echo "<div>" . time() . ": Iteration $i</div>";
   sleep(1);
   ob_flush();
   flush();
 } 
 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

You should not flush often because you force php to process messages and this will increase the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You might put `\n` in `echo`  or `print` to flush the buffer.